# Permanently (301) redirect all urls to homepage with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website with lots of page and I want all pages/urls will be permanently redirected (301) to homepage by htaccess. Can we please let me how could I achieve this?

I want something like that.

`mywebsite.com` to `https://www.mywebsite.com/`

`mywebsite.com/page` to `https://www.mywebsite.com/`

`mywebsite.com/assets/img.jpg` to `https://www.mywebsite.com/`

Here is my current htaccess lines

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please do add your htaccess rule file into your question in text format, thank you.

Comment: thank you for reply. 
I've added these in the question.

Comment: Thanks for showing it, kindly do update the same in your question.

Comment: Remove the two RewriteConds then? Those are what is currently checking whether the request matched any physically existing folder or file, and only rewrite to the index.php, if not.

Comment: @CBroe 
thank you for suggation. 
I've removed those 2 lines form htaccess but not redirecting when I point https://www.mywebsite.com/faq/

Comment: Ah yes, because it still goes into the WordPress routing engine then, because the request was rewritten to the index.php. So what do you actually want to show as the home page here - a page still served by WordPress, or something else?

Comment: Change `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` with `RewriteRule . / [L,R]`

Comment: thank you @anubhava It's worked.
Really grateful to you guys who are replied.

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this single rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# redirect to landing page if it is
# non-www or non-https or any URL other than landing page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . https://www.%1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @itshimelkazi: Suggest you to use this rule that handles all 3 conditions.